Oracle APEX 24.1: Generate page links from placeholders in text
I'm converting an old Perl/MySQL database application to Oracle APEX and there's one feature in the old system that I've been unable to figure out a way to do...
Assume that each table is made up of a listing screen (interactive grid), a view only screen (form with all fields set to read only) and an input/edit screen (a second form); and has an ID (Primary Key), Name, and Comments (textarea) field although they obviously have many other fields as well.  For this, assume we have tables called table_1, table_2, and table_3 with sequential ID, then Name with values name_1, name_2, and name_3 for each.
The current system uses what they refer to as "free-form linking" so that table:name  entered on the input screen will display a link to the actual record or records that match the name.
Example:
If they enter <table_2:name_3> into the Comments field on the input form for table_1, then on the view form for table_1, it shows as a clickable link to that record and if name_3 isn't unique (it isn't required to be), it will show a list of matching records.
Any way to do this in APEX?  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
I've tried changing the URL to use the Name field instead of the ID (primary key) and it failed.  I don't see a way to script the filter or any other way to do this.

This can be achieved using a report with source type "PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL Query". Example on emp/dept sample tables. Users can enter ENAME:KING to get a link to the form for KING or DEPT:ACCOUNTING to get a link to the form for ACCOUNTING. Example is on page 142, the links to the forms do not pass primary key arguments but that should be trivial.
Page Item
Create a page item of type Text Field P142_SEARCH_TERM
Classic report
Create a classic report of type "PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL Query". Use the following source:
DECLARE
    l_query varchar2(4000);
    l_table_name varchar2(400);
    l_key varchar2(400);
    l_search_term_t apex_t_varchar2 := apex_t_varchar2();
    --ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count
    subscript_beyond_count EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (subscript_beyond_count, -06533);
    invalid_search_args EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        l_search_term_t := apex_string.split(NVL(:P142_SEARCH_TERM,'EMP:KING'),':');
        l_table_name := l_search_term_t(1);
        l_key := l_search_term_t(2);
    EXCEPTION WHEN subscript_beyond_count THEN
        RAISE invalid_search_args;
    END;
    IF l_table_name = 'EMP' THEN
        l_query := 
        q'!select
                          ename,
                          apex_page.get_url(
                            p_page => 142
                          )
                       from
                          emp
                       where 
                          ename = '%0'!';
    ELSIF l_table_name = 'DEPT' THEN 
        l_query := 
        q'!select
                          dname,
                          apex_page.get_url(
                            p_page => 141
                          )
                       from
                          dept
                       where 
                          dname = '%0'!';
    ELSE        
        RAISE invalid_search_args;
    END IF;
    l_query := apex_string.format(l_query, l_key);
    apex_debug.info(p_message =>'SO Debug: '||l_query);
    return(l_query);
EXCEPTION WHEN invalid_search_args THEN 
    l_query := 
    q'!select
                      'Invalid search argument: "'||:P142_SEARCH_TERM||'"'
                   from
                      dual!';
    return(l_query);
END;

Set Page Items to Submit, Generic Column Names and Generic Columns Count (this is needed because otherwise APEX will add an order by clause from the INIT clause)

Dynamic Action
Create a dynamic action on change of P142_SEARCH_TERM to refresh the classic report region.

I guess I needed to be a little clearer.  This is a textarea, not a text field.  It's a varchar2 (4000) and can be a complete narrative and include more than one free-form link.  I Seem to always fall back on using cars for examples, so imagine a book on care maintenance.  One chapter includes regular maintenance that is required for a car and includes links to chapters on changing the oil, air filter, checking the transmission fluid, etc.

Yeah... you lost me there. Can you update your question with a very detailed example of what you'd put in an what output you'd expect to see ? Your comment didn't make me any wiser :)

I keep running out of characters... Sample:
T1"General_Maint", T2 "Lube", T3 "Filters".
Record from Chapter 1 comments entered as:

Every 6 months, change the oil Lube:Oil and lube Lube:Lube
Every year, change the air filter Filters:Air_Filter and cabin filter Flters:Cabin_Filter

and after saving, reads as:

Every 6 months, change the oil link and lubelink.
Every year, change the air filter link and cabin filter link.


Table: General_Maint
ID: 1
Name: Scheduled_Maintenance
Comments: As above.
ID: 2
Name: Periodic_Unscheduled_Maintenanace
Comment: Other stuff with links

Table: Lube
ID: 1
Name: Oil
Comments: Full description perhaps with links to types of oil, tools needed, etc.
ID: 2
Name: Lube
Comments: Full description of how to change.

Table: Filters
ID: 1
Name: Air_Filter
Comments: Description of how to change..
ID: 2
Name: Cabin_Filter
Comments: Similar to above


Ah now I get it. It's similar to what I showed but you want a generated text with links to the individual records on pages instead of an actual report correct ?

Check my other answer.

To parse a text and replace placeholders with link to other pages, the following can be done.
Example: text can contain links to pages EMP and DEPT referencing employee name and department name.
Page item
Name: P276_PLACEHOLDER_TEXT
Type: Textarea
Button (submits page)
Note: this can also done with a dynamic action and a refresh of the region. In that case use the "Items to Submit" attribute of the region.
Region (type Dynamic Content)
Source:
declare
    l_result clob DEFAULT EMPTY_CLOB();
    l_regex  VARCHAR2(30) := '(\<[a-z0-9:]+\>)';
    l_search_term_t apex_t_varchar2 := apex_t_varchar2();
    l_page   VARCHAR2(100);
    l_item_name   VARCHAR2(100);
    l_key    VARCHAR2(100);   
    l_parsed_placeholder VARCHAR2(4000); 
    l_link VARCHAR2(4000); 
begin
    l_result := :P276_PLACEHOLDER_TEXT;
    -- loop through all placeholders in text. Regexp looks for strings without spaces between < and >.
    FOR r_placeholders IN 
    (
        WITH t(valt) AS
        (SELECT :P276_PLACEHOLDER_TEXT as valt FROM dual)
            SELECT
              translate(regexp_substr(valt,l_regex,1,level,'i'),'*<>','_') as c
            FROM t
            CONNECT BY translate(regexp_substr(valt,l_regex,1,level,'i'),'<>','_') IS NOT NULL
    )
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            l_search_term_t := apex_string.split(r_placeholders.c,':');
            -- decide what page number and page item name based on the first part of the placeholder 
            l_page := CASE l_search_term_t(1)
                        WHEN 'EMP' THEN 277
                        WHEN 'DEPT' THEN 278
                      ELSE NULL END;
            l_item_name := CASE l_search_term_t(1)
                        WHEN 'EMP' THEN 'P277_ENAME'
                        WHEN 'DEPT' THEN 'P278_DNAME'
                      ELSE NULL END;
            -- build url to target page          
            l_parsed_placeholder := apex_page.get_url (p_page => l_page, p_items => l_item_name, p_values => l_search_term_t(2));
        END;    
        -- build full link with orignal placeholder and href to page
        l_link := apex_string.format('<a href="%0">%1</a>',l_parsed_placeholder,r_placeholders.c);
        -- replace the placeholder with the link
        l_result := REPLACE(l_result,'<'||r_placeholders.c||'>',l_link);
    END LOOP;

    return l_result;
end;

Result

Notes
This code is pretty raw, it needs a lot of error handling added to work properly (eg error handling when non-existing pages are in placeholders, error handling when placeholder is incomplete, etc) but this should get you going.
